# Storage data created by user on phone. Please see this post

Tags: java, android

My situation is the next one. I am creating an app when you can do a survey, and then, you can see survey answers, clicking on a button, in the applicacion, without going to phone files or something like that. I've created like 55% of that application, but the other 45% is the most important. How many possibilites there are, or what can i do to achieve that, when a person click an in-app button, could see survey answers. I did the interface, buttons, textview, etc.. I created a database, thiniking that creating it, it would be possible to achieve that i want to. I expect to do a system when you can do a survey, and then, press a button, open a new activity and see survey answers. When you close app and open again, survey answers doesn't disappear, they still saved. Thanks!

Here is my code of the survey, XML and JAVA:

```
Button sig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.env); // cargo el boton
    encuestadoSQLiteHelper encuestado = new encuestadoSQLiteHelper(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1); // base de datos
    final SQLiteDatabase db = encuestado.getWritableDatabase();


    sig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            EditText preg5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            EditText preg4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            Spinner cur = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerp);
            EditText nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            RadioGroup gruporadio = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo1);
            RadioGroup gruporadio2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo2);
            RadioGroup gruporadio3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo3);
            String strNombre = nom.getText().toString();
            String nombre = "PabloGonzalez";
            String curso =  cur.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String strPregCinco = preg5.getText().toString();
            String strPregCuatro = preg4.getText().toString();

            if(gruporadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || gruporadio2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1  || gruporadio3.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 )
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡No marcaste ninguna respuesta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else if (strNombre.matches("") || strPregCinco.matches("") || strPregCuatro.matches(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Dejaste campos vacíos!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else if(db == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No funciona la base de datos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                db.close();
            }

            else
            {
                Intent i = new Intent (encuesta.this, res8.class);
                i.putExtra("nombre", strNombre);
                startActivity(i);
                Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(pas);
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Encuestado (nombre) " +
                        "VALUES ('" + nombre +"')");
                db.close();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                                String currentDBPath = "/data/com.example.pablo.myapplication/databases/DBEncuestad‌​o";
                                String backupDBPath = "backdatabase.sqlite";
                                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                                    src.close();
                                    dst.close();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("error in data base copy:"+e);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

If you can see, there is a database, but i dont know if it is not necessary or yes.

XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:text="Nombre del encuestado:"
        android:id="@+id/nomb"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ems="15"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Curso:"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
    android:text="1. ¿Cuánto tiempo tarda usted desde su casa al colegio?"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />



    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/Grupo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1/2 hora a 1 hora" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 hora o 2 horas" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2 horas o más" />
    </RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:text="2. ¿Cuánto tiempo tarda desde el colegio a su casa?"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/Grupo2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1/2 hora a 1 hora" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 hora o 2 horas" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2 horas o más" />
    </RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:text="3. ¿Cuáles de las siguientes zonas de Bogotá está localizado su domicilio?"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/Grupo3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Norte de Bogotá (calle 72 en adelante)" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Suba (noroccidente)" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Centro - Chapinero - Teusaquillo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Alrededores de Bogotá" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sur de Bogotá" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Occidente (Puente Aranada - Fontibón - Engativá)" />
    </RadioGroup>


<TextView
    android:text="4. Si usted fuera alcalde de Bogotá, ¿que solución propondría para mejorar la movilidad de Bogotá?"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="#e4e4e4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="5. ¿Cómo cree que influye la movilidad en la calidad de vida de las personas?"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#e4e4e4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Enviar encuesta"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/env"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And activity where i want to show the answers is res8.java

Comment: what have you done, what do you want to do, and how do you expect to do what you want to do?

Comment: I did the interface, buttons, textview, etc.. I created a database, thiniking that creating it, it was possible to achieve that i want to. I expect to do a system when you can do a survey, and then, press a button, open a new activity and see survey answers. When you close app and open again, survey answers doesn't disappear, they still saved.

Comment: i advise you to update your question with details of your persistence implementation, so you can have your database working

Comment: by details i mean code. Defining a table, inserting and retrieving data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, Just create a model class like getter and setter first having methods like getQuestion(), setQuestion(), getAnswer(), setAnswer(). And after that , when user answering your survey question just create a object of that model class say like:-

```
ArrayList<MyModel> datalist = new ArrayList();
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.setQuestion(list.get(i).question);
    model.setAnswer(list.get(i).answer);
    ....
    ....
  dataList.add(model);
```

like this just capture all user input data , No need for the database in this.

Here list is the list of all question you are having ....

And when you want to getData ...just call datalist.get(i).getQuestion and similarly with answer.

Comment: And how can i do that with the code that i posted on the question?